# Changing time zone on all timestamps using mutate_if and force_tz

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, lubridate

I'm pulling data from a Postgres DB using the `RPostgreSQL`, which casts timestamps to the system time zone on import into R. So, after import I would like to set the time zone of all timestamps to UTC. I thought I would be able to elegantly do this using `dplyr` and `lubridate`, like so:

```
df %>%
   mutate_if(lubridate::is.POSIXct, lubridate::force_tz(., tzone='UTC')) -> df
```

But this throws

```
Error in UseMethod("as.fun_list") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.fun_list' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

so I'm obviously using `mutate_if()` incorrectly

Comment: To use the dot notation you would need to wrap the function in `funs`.  However, per [this issue on github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2089) you would have to actually load the package rather than using `::`.

Comment: @aosmith Wanna submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the dot notation in `mutate_if`, the function must be wrapped in `funs`.

```
library(lubridate)

df %>%
    mutate_if(is.POSIXct, funs(force_tz(., tzone='UTC')))
```

Currently, however, you cannot use the `package::` notation within `funs`.  Instead you would have to explicitly load the package as I did above (relevant github issue [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2089)).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate_if(lubridate::is.POSIXct,
                   function(x) lubridate::force_tz(x, tzone='UTC')) -> df
```

as does this similar `purrr` solution:

```
df %>%
  purrr::map_if(lubridate::is.POSIXct,
                ~ lubridate::force_tz(., tzone='UTC')) %>%
  as_data_frame -> df
```

Is this as elegant as it gets?

Comment: I'm inclined to think so, yes.